# Change format of date with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

How can I insert new `\Datetime()  jj-mm-aaaa` format with Symfony2 ? or if is it impossible how to show it in this format in Twig N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the [Date Twig Filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html),

```
{{ yourDateTimeObject|date("d-m-Y") }}
```